# Do we ever see a trainer with multiple Pokémon of the same species?

Tags: pokemon

In the animé series of *Pokémon*, do we ever see a trainer with multiple specimen of the same species?

How about different *Pokémon* of the same *form* (in other words, different evolutions)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes.

In relation to the TV show, 
[Brittany](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Brittany_(EP243)) and  [Bailey](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bailey) both have two of the same Pokemon, a twinned pair of Igglybuffs and a twinned pair of Bellossoms respectively.

These two characters are quite unusual because they don't really fight with their Pokemon, instead using them in their stage shows in the episodes [Flower Power](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP122) and [Same Old Song and Dance](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP243)

**Brittany**
[image]

**Bailey**
[image]

In the episode [Espeon, Not Included](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP226) we meet the Kimono Sisters. These trainers exclusively train Eeveelutions such as Eevee, Jolteon, Umbreon, Flareon, etc

---

If you're happy with *game references* then there are *multiple* instances of players owning several of the same type such as [Janine](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Janine), [Koga](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Koga) and [Jasmine](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Jasmine)

Comment: Wasn't there an episode in the original (US) show where someone owned all 3 Evee evolutions? Would that count?

Comment: @Ellesedil - See edit :-)

Comment: Also Ash caught about 30 Tauros (Taurai?) in the safari zone.